# Saving dynamically created page to file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how can I save dynamically created (div appending using js) page to new file? 
Locally, to a server - it doesn't matter.
I want to save whole page.

Comment: How do you create it? With echos, etc? 
You could just add whatever you echo into a variable and safe that at the end.

Comment: if you don't want to change the logic (like using serverside language to grab & insert the div), you need something such as phantomJS.

Comment: I personally use smarty templates to create pages dynamically.
When needed, instead of displaying the final page I put it in a variable to put it in a file or an email.

Comment: You might browse the code driving tiddlywiki.com, it does this dynamic saving somehow. Look for a synch.js file, or look in the core. Getting the html is easy (jQuery), but forcing it to a file save as, is the part that I wonder about. Posting it to a server is easy too once you have the string.